# I have install Nextjs app. But could not started the app. Its stopped immediately. My terminal shows below like -

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

I have install Nextjs app. But could not started the app. My terminal shows below like -

PS D:\Coding\Next JS\my-app> npm run dev

> realtor@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

I deleted node modules , package.json and install it again. I also updated node but it doesn't work.